# WPF validation UpdateSourceTrigger Doesnt fire

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

i am trying to validate some controls and when i enter break points and run the application my customValidation class gets called and i can go through my breakpoints and the logic seems to work fine but when i enter data in the textbox the UpdateSourceTrigger doesnt fire and the textbox border is still red, i am posting my code please tell me what am i doing wrong.

the Custom Class:

```
 public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
       // try
        //{
            string letter = "/[a-zA-Z]/";
            string number = "/[0-9]/";
            string val = null;
            if (value != null)
            {
              val = value.ToString();
            }
            String regex="/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/";
            if(this.ControlName.ToString()=="username")
            {
                    if (val == "" || val == null )
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid Username ");
                    }
            }
            else if(this.ControlName.ToString()=="password")
            {

                    if (val == null || val == "" || val.Length < 4 || val.Length > 15 )
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a Valid password");
                    }
            }
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
       // }
    }
```

the XAML page :

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Name="txtusername" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="username" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:CustomValidator ControlName="username" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: if(this.ControlName.ToString()=="username") is it "username" or "txtusername"?

Comment: no it is username and i have debugged that class and havent found any faults, it seems that the class is returning the expected results but the problem is that when i enter some value in the textbox the class doesnt get called again

Comment: Can anyone help here please... i am kinda stuck

Comment: can you please send the code for the class (the class containing the Property "username")

Comment: Add code for class which contains Username property. because you missed property changed event handler in you username property.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txtusername" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="username" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <l:CustomValidator ControlName="username" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Test();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomValidator : ValidationRule
    {
        public string ControlName { get; set; }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            string letter = "/[a-zA-Z]/";
            string number = "/[0-9]/";
            string val = null;
            if (value != null)
            {
                val = value.ToString();
            }

            String regex = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/";
            if (this.ControlName.ToString() == "username")
            {
                if (val == "" || val == null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid Username ");
                }
            }
            else if (this.ControlName.ToString() == "password")
            {
                if (val == null || val == "" || val.Length < 4 || val.Length > 15)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a Valid password");
                }
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couple of Questions here: 1 - why do you set the dataContext of the window to the class? and by doing that what happens? 2- I have the username property defined in my users class if i set the path= username how will it detect the username, since its in the different class? and do i need to have my validations also in the users class which contains all the data members?

Comment: the Test class here is an example. I dont have your class which contains property 'username', so i created a test class with the same. Try changing your biniding in your XAML.

Comment: yes i understood that but why do we need to relate the input value with the property of the class , why cant we just pass the value and validate it?

Comment: You have a property in a class 'username' which is bound to a textbox text and needs to be validated. For validation you are creating a ValidationRule which validates the property. When text changes, property changes and this leads to property validation. Sorry i cant understand what do you mean by 'why do we need to relate the input value with the property of the class , why cant we just pass the value'.

Comment: This article should give you enough info on Validation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. what i meant was that why do we need bind the input value of the textbox with the username property of the class USers. why cant we  just pass the input value of the textbox directly to the validationRule and check if the value is correct or not and accordingly decide whether to pass the input value for further processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75808/discussion-between-faisal-malikyar-and-lerner1225).